# Get PHP file inside HTML document

Tags: php, jquery, echo

Suppose I have PHP file with this code:

```
 <?php echo date('l, F jS, Y'); ?>
```

This will echo the date. How do I set this date inside HTML page? I know I can put the PHP code in my HTML like this:

```
<body>
  <?php echo date('l, F jS, Y'); ?> 
</body>
```

But what I want is this:

```
<body>
  "The date retrieved by the file php_code.php"
</body>
```

Do I have to use Javascript/Jquery GET? Or is there a simple more straightforward way of doing this?

Is it possible to just give the url of the php file in the document?

Comment: The real question is 'why'? What is preventing you from doing it the first way?  Are you resource constrained?

Comment: you can use <?php include 'vphp_code.php'; ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy when you're using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('php_code.php', function(data) {
    $('div#result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

**Edit:** this approach may work even better (based on your cross-domain comment):

#### 1. Wrap your PHP-response in a javascript callback:

```
<?php
...
echo "callback(" . json_encode($response) . ");"
?>
```

#### 2. Include it in your html file:

2a. On load (add it to your `head`):

```
<script src="http://yourserver.com/php_code.php"></script>
```

2b. Or on runtime (add it anywhere in your javascript):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://yourserver.com/php_code.php";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

#### 3. Setup a callback

```
function callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

It's called JSONP and it's a lot easier to implement when using cross domain requests. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting your date into your body, as you mentioned yourself:

1. Synchronously
2. Asynchronously

Pt. 1 is achieved by your example, using PHP to directly render the date inside the HTML container.

Pt. 2 can be achieved by ex. Javascript. I'm not sure if there are any other ways of doing this, but Javascript is a sure winner. It can, however, be done in a number of different ways - but the easiest being the version Tim van Elsloo pointed out.

Comment: I just saw the "I want to sell my document but without the php, I want to keep the php on my server".

You will have trouble using AJAX on different servers. You could do a `file_get_contents("http://example.com/date.php")` and reaching it synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

do simply : [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$.get('php_server_file.php', function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not good solution but this can solve the problem.

Add div element in body.

```
  <body>
     <div id="mydiv"></div>
  </body>
```

Then put this code in

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.get("php_code.php",function(data){
          $('.mydiv').html(data);
      });
   });
  </script>
```